# HTML Elements all falling in on themselves Bulma Framework SASS Customization

Tags: html, css, sass, bulma

[Messy Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBNSC.png)

I'm relatively new to Bulma and I've just been trying to customize my css, and after customization the screen has collapsed on itself. Does anyone know the usual reason why two elements wont space themselves away from each other? For example **why is the greenbar half hidden under the navbar?**

```
<main>
<nav>
</nav>
<div className="container">
Bunch of random Content
</div>
</main>
```

The above layout seems to result in things piling on top of each other, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing a `>` after `"container"`. It's impossible to tell anything beyond that if we don't see any of your CSS.

Comment: Oops, sorry. The Css is the entire bulma framework library imported onto a SASS sheet. It seems just the Nav was having overflow problems, I just gave the next item a margin-top and the rest stacked normally. I'm not sure why only the NAV didn't have inline properties